# Todos los php bin/console .... que hago, Abortan

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Tengo un proyecto symfony y me he dado cuenta que cualquier consulta tipos `php bin/console` que haga, termina en Aborted.
Ejemplo:
`php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

```
 Careful, database "advSoftware" will be purged. Do you want to continue? (yes/no) [no]:
 >

  Aborted.
```

`php bin/console make:auth`

```
 What style of authentication do you want? [Empty authenticator]:
  [0] Empty authenticator
  [1] Login form authenticator
 >

  Aborted.
```

Alguien podría ayudarme?

Directamente Aborta la consulta, no me deja escribir nada

Answer (score 0):

Hace unas semanas leí que había un bug en la versión de PHP 7.4 que solo pasa en windows:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78883
https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4961

Parece que en 7.4.1 Se iba a publicar el arreglo.

Tienes dos opciones, bajar la versión a 7.3 o intentar subir tu versión de PHP a 7.1.1+.

Saludos

Comment: y no hay ninguna informacion en los archivos de log de la aplicacion?

Comment: Diría que no, parece que tiene que ver con la salida estándar y además no da un error interno o algo similar, solo tiene ese comportamiento que comentas.

Comment: si te es mucho lio pasar de una version a otra, yo te propondria que utilizaras docker. asi podrias crear instancia de un php mas actualizado y usarlo en tu proyecto.